# Ubuntu Dual boot breaks keyboard in WIndows 7

Tags: dual-boot, keyboard, hp

I have a HP ProBook 4530s Notebook PC. Main OS is WIndows 7 pro. I tried to install Ubuntu (from Windows with dual boot) several times and the result is the same. Ubuntu works fine but there is a strange issue with keyboard back in Windows. Some keys wont produce any output, some with a delay.

Have anyone experienced such issues?

Comment: Have you tried changing Keyboard settings from System Settings>>Under Hardware select Keyboard. Try changing the speed.

Comment: Should the setting change after Ubuntu installing?

Comment: What kind of keyboard? PS2, USB, Wireless? Though I can think of no situations where changing to another OS would affect the keyboard...

Comment: It's integrated, it's a laptop